# All of a suden CPU over heat error on boot

Tags: cpu, desktop-computer, overheating

I recently moved houses and took my desktop computer with me. Before moving, I dusted it out using compressed air and took the heat sink off the CPU and dusted it out too. When I reassembled the computer and turned it on, it worked the first time, but when I restarted it got the error message that the CPU is overheating and to press F1 which led to this screen

[image: bios screen]

I can see the fan on the heatsink spinning so I think it's working. The temperature reads 93 Celcius, is it possible for the CPU to be this hot? How do I fix this?

UPDATE: I got a new cpu fan and put it on and still the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

For the CPU to overheat that fast, there must be a problem with the way the heat sink is installed, or the CPU's fan isn't working.

Start by checking if the fan is turning.  If not, check its connection.

If it does turn, it could be that the heat sink is not seated properly or you haven't installed new thermal paste properly.

You should consequently take it off again, reapply thermal paste as directed in the package, reseat the heat sink tightly, and try again.

Comment: I turned it off for an hour and now it's working again. The fan was always spinning. I didn't reapply thermal paste when I took off the heat sink. I should ask, what exactly is the difference between heatsink and fan?

Comment: The heat sink is the metal part designed as a radiator to dissipate the heat.  The fan sits on top of it.

Comment: Without new thermal paste, you can be sure that it will heat up much more than before.

Comment: Oh really? I red you never need to replace the thermal paste unless you replace the whole heat sink http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/285023-28-long-thermal-paste-replaced

Comment: When you remove it, you remove the tight connection between the heat sink and the CPU.  It acts a bit like glue but also has the ability to efficiently transfer heat.

Comment: **I didn't reapply thermal paste** You need thermal paste.  If you apply thermal paste you will do permanent damage to your hardware.

Comment: I'm going to need some more advice. I removed the old thermal paste and applied new one. I don't think the heat sink is locking into the mobo right. I never hear a clicking sound in opposite pins; I can only get 2 of the 4 pins to lock in place. I think it's an Intel stock cooler.

Comment: Sorry for you.  Welcome to the wonderful world of CPU fans.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I notice when I take off the heat sink, the thermal paste hasn't really been spread around. Does this mean I should apply more thermal paste? My understanding is to put a small amount on the cpu and then when the heat sink presses down on it, it will be spread around. But this doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: You need to follow the provided instructions.  It's usually ideal to spread it evenly by doing big zigzags.  Of course you don't want to put too much on the edges.

Comment: And you do need to press firmly, but don't break the motherboard or the attachment parts.

Comment: It must be something else. I applied thermal paste and heard all 4 pins click in on the heat sink. Still CPU over heat error. I took off heatsink and thermal paste had been smeared around so that's proof it had made contact with the CPU plate.